# How to find the axis of highest variance of a set of 2D points?

Tags: geometry, variance

I'm trying to get some insight into how a "body" of 2D points is laid out. I represent my points as two vectors, $X$ and $Y$.

I'd like to be able to define the axis along which the points are most "spread out", e.g.:

I can easily get $varX$ and $varY$, which tell me something about how spread out the points are with respect to the $x$ and $y$ directions. And I could also get $var(.5X+.5Y)$ or $var(.5X-.5Y)$, which tell me the same thing for the diagonals.

I'm interested in finding $max_{(a,b)}var(aX + bY)$ where $a+b = 1$.

My goal is to use $a$ and $b$ to create an ellipse centered at the mean location of the group of points, with its major axis having slope $\frac{a}{b}$.

What's the best way to find $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The only way is formulating a maximization problem. There is not a simpler way to maximize the variance without calculating it. Unless you are assuming some stochastic relation in your 2D  body, which i guess, is not stochastic at all!

Comment: @hyprfrcb can you advise as to what I can expect for an optimization problem, then? E.g. I can't hope for a single local maximum, but can I trust that my variance is continuous?

Comment: Well this would go on different possible setups for that optimization. Taking only the values over a ray?, or calculating the full variance directionally, or over a cone? Maybe a better insight of the application would be valuable to select the best framework.

Comment: Yes the variance is continuous and indeed leading to some trivial PCA analysis, but i think that could not the best if you want to observe specific shapes in a body.

Comment: @hyprfrcb if it helps - I'd like to be able to draw an ellipse that bounds some % of points - perhaps 99 or 95, as a form of outlier removal

Comment: So PCA is clearly the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your answer is [PCA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)?

$(a,b)$ is calculated straightfordward from the first component of the PCA.